# Как с помощью ajax отправить на сервер данные в формате json

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

Как правильно отправить данные json от пользователя на сервер node.js и как их принять

Comment: Гугл в помощь: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отправки есть [XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest) или [Fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch). А принять можно например тем же [Express](https://expressjs.com/ru/)

Как пример отправки и приема

Как  пример:

**NodeJS - сервер на порту 3000:**

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world: '+req.query.q)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

**Бразуер JS:**

Вариант на [Fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch):

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/?q=mydata')
.then((response) => {
    return response.text();
})
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Вариант [XHR](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest) :

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/?q=mydata');

xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log(`Ошибка ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
  } else {
    console.log(xhr.response);
  }
};


xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert("Запрос не удался");
};
```

Вариант с [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/?q=mydata",
  cache: false
}).done(function( response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Каждый запрос во всех этих вариантах делается на `localhost:3000` передавая в `GET` параметрах текст `mydata`. Результатом ответа севера который будет выведен в консоль браузера будет: `hello world: mydata`